# Complicated Query Logic

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a somewhat complicated mySQL query I want to run, and I am having trouble thinking of how to write it.

Basically I have three tables:

```
a(aid, name);
b(bid, val);
ab(aid, bid)
```

What I want to do is create a query that creates a table like this:

```
c(aid, valSum);
```

I want valSum to start at 0 and add the value of bid.val of every relation between aid and bid.

For example:

```
a:
+-----+------+
| aid | name |
+-----+------+
| 1   |  Joe |
| 2   |  Jon |
| 3   |  Max |
+-----+------+

b:
+-----+-----+
| bid | val |
+-----+-----+
| 1   |   2 |
| 2   |   4 |
| 3   |   6 |
+-----+-----+

ab:
+-----+-----+
| aid | bid |
+-----+-----+
| 1   |   1 |
| 1   |   2 |
| 2   |   2 |
| 2   |   3 |
| 3   |   1 |
| 3   |   2 |
| 3   |   3 |
+-----+-----+

c:
+-----+--------+
| aid | valSum |
+-----+--------+
| 1   |      6 |
| 2   |     10 |
| 3   |     12 |
+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like below:

```
SELECT a.aid, SUM(b.val) AS valSum
FROM a
INNER JOIN ab ON a.aid = ab.aid
INNER JOIN b ON ab.bid = b.bid
GROUP BY a.aid
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to join to table `a` at all:

```
SELECT ab.aid, sum(b.val) AS valSum
FROM   ab
JOIN   b USING (bid)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

... except to list rows from `a` without any match in `ab`. You would have to use **`LEFT JOIN`** in this case, though:

```
SELECT a.aid, sum(b.val) AS valSum
FROM   a
LEFT   JOIN ab USING (aid)
LEFT   JOIN  b USING (bid);
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`valSum` would be `NULL` for those rows.